Orange Background after moved window
If a window is moved using the key combination "Power button + arrow key left/right/up/down", part of the screen appears with an orange background. How can I deactivate this function or the orange background?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com

